# Can you construct a Vitali set under ZF?

Tags: measure-theory, set-theory, axiom-of-choice

A Vitali set $V$ is a complete set of representatives of $\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Q}$ in the interval $[0,1]$. Translating $V$ by all rationals in $[-1,1]$ leads to a proof that it is not measurable.

Now, there are models of ZF in which every subset of $\mathbb{R}$ is measurable, so the answer to my question ought to be no.

My confusion is, why does the following approach fail?

Under the assumption that L=V (the constructible universe = the Von Neumann universe), the axiom of choice holds by using a well-ordering of L.

This leads me to suspect that even without L=V, there should be choice functions at least for families of constructible sets, though I might be misunderstanding something.

$\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Q}$ seems like a constructible set, so why can we not construct a Vitali set in ZF?

Comment: While the title question is a duplicate, the body (about why you can't "lift from $L$") isn't. I've voted to reopen. EDIT: apparently I have unilateral reopening powers now. I didn't know that, so my apologies for their quick deployment here!

Comment: @NoahSchweber Can you please use those unilateral reopening powers on the economy? :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is indeed the case that, if $X$ is a constructible instance of choice *(I'm being a bit vague about this, but e.g. maybe take this to mean that $X=(A,E)$ where $A\in L$ is a set and $E\in L$ is an equivalence relation on $A$)*, then $X$ has a choice function in $V$ even if $V\not=L$. This is because being a choice function/transversal/etc. is absolute between $V$ and $L$, so that anything which $L$ thinks is a witness to choice not failing at $X$ actually is a witness to choice not failing at $X$.

However, this does **not** let us build a transversal for $\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Q}$ - rather, it only gives us a transversal for $\color{red}{\mathbb{R}^L}/\mathbb{Q}$, the set of reals **in $L$** modulo the rational difference relation *(note that $\mathbb{Q}$ and the rational difference relation are each absolute between $V$ and $L$)*. So indeed we have the following, assuming merely $\mathsf{ZF}$ in $V$: if $\mathbb{R}=\mathbb{R}^L$ then there is a Vitali set. However, this still leaves open the possibility that $V$ fails to have any true Vitali sets by virtue of having (to start with) lots of reals which $L$ doesn't "see."

Comment: Thank you! I think that's what I was missing, that while we can define a version of R in the constructible universe there is no guarantee that this definition matches with "the" real numbers R without V=L. Is that the idea?

Comment: Does it follow that, in models where all subsets of R are Lebesgue measurable, R^L must have measure 0?

Comment: @user64480 "while we can define a version of R in the constructible universe there is no guarantee that this definition matches with "the" real numbers R without V=L. Is that the idea?" That's absolutely right. "Does it follow that, in models where all subsets of R are Lebesgue measurable, R^L must have measure 0?" That doesn't follow immediately *(as far as I can tell)*, but in fact it happens to be true. In fact, a model where all sets are measurable must be extremely far from $L$ in many ways, and that's one of them. Relevant terms include **descriptive set theory** and **large cardinals**.

Comment: Thanks! My reasoning was that if R^L had a positive measure then the same proof which shows that a transversal for R/Q is not measurable would work for a transversal for R^L/Q.

Comment: @user64480 Oh, yes, derp - I was being slow. :P